# Performance of Stateless Authentication in SPA and SSO (Single Sign On)

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, authentication

If I have a SPA (Single Page Application - developed with BackboneJS) and want to have a stateless RESTful backend API for its data. I like how 3rd party single sign on makes things so easy for the user, thus will like it use it.

But I understand in a stateless environment like this, authentication is done on every request? If so, if I am using a 3rd party SSO, eg. GitHub, won't I need to goto GitHub to authenticate the user everytime? Whats the best practice for such situations? I believe its a very common use case? - I allow the user to login via Google/GitHub or something, then get data from some stateless REST API

Comment: if you authenticate the page, you should be golden until a refresh, which in an SPA is never...

Answer (score 14):

### Disclaimer :)

Having implemented such a thing for my product, and sharing many of your concerns and tech (especially SPA with Backbone using a 100% stateless REST backend) I can tell you what are my thoughs about this, making clear that this doesn't want to be "the answer" but rather a conversation starter to learn from the resulting discussion, as I think I too have quite a bit to learn on the topic.

---

First of all, I think you should go 100% stateless. And by 100%, I mean 100% :) Not only your API layer should be stateless, but the whole application (except client, of course). Moving sessions on a different layer (eg. redis) just moves the problem a bit, but doesn't solve it. Everything (especially scaling) will be so much easier, and you will thank yourself about this decision later on.

So, yes, you need to have **authentication on every request**. But this doesn't mean that you have to hit the auth provider every time. One of the things that I learned is that allowing an user to authenticate via FB/GitHub/Whatever (from now on, *remote service*) is just a mean to ease the pain of signup/signin, nothing else. You still have to grow your personal database of users. Of course, each user will be associated to a "remote" users, but soon after the authentication has been performed, the app should reference "your" user, and not the "remote" user (eg. GitHub user).

### Implementation

Here's what I've implemented:

1. My API methods **always** need an authentication token. The auth token is a hash that represent an user of my system, so that when I call `POST /api/board?name=[a_name]&auth=[my_token]`, I know who's calling, can check permissions and can associate the newly created entity `board` to the correct user.
2. The said token has nothing to do with remote services' tokens. The logic they are computed from is specific to my app. But it maps an user of mine, that is also mapped to a remote user, so no information is lost in case it's needed.
3. Here's how I authenticate the user via a remote service. I implement the remote authentication as specified in the service documentation. Usually it is OAuth or OAuth-like, this means that in the end I get an `authToken` that represent the remote user. This token has 2 purposes:

   - I can use it to call API methods on the remote service acting as the user
   - I have the guarantee that the user is who it says it is, at least by the means of the remote service
4. As soon as your user authenticated itself with the remote service, you load or create the matching user in your system. If the user with `remote_id: GitHub_abc123` is not present in your system, you create it, otherwise you load it. Let's say this user has `id: MyApp_def456`. You create also an `authToken` with your own logic that will represent the user `MyApp_def456` and pass it to the client (cookies are ok!!)
5. Back to point 1 :)

---

### Notes

The authentication is performed at every request and this means that you deal with hashes and crypto functions, that by definitions are slow. Now, if you use `bcrypt` with 20 iterations, this will kill your app. I use it to store the passwords of the users when they log in, but then use a less heavy algorithm for the `authToken` (I personally use an hash comparable to `SHA-256`). This tokens can be short lived (let's say less than the average time to crack them) and are fairly easy to compute on a server machine. There's not an exact answer here. Try different approaches, measure and decide. What I am sure about, instead, is that I prefer to have this kind of problems than session problems. If I need to compute more hashes, or faster, I add CPU power. With sessions and a clustered environment, you have memory issues, load balancing and sticky sessions problems, or other moving pieces (redis).

Obiouvsly, `HTTPS` is absolutely mandatory because `authToken` is always passed as a parameter.

Comment: About point 3. How do you make sure that userA is the real userA and not someone else? Also: if for every call you pass the token but the api is restless, how do you check that the token is valid? If you query your DB we're back to square one.

Comment: Please note that cache is fundamentally different from session. If your "session" simply means keeping the tokens in memory to avoid hitting a DB, then you are talking about a cache and not a session. So you are not back to square one, as after the first call the user token will very likely live in a cache between your app and a DB. It's really a non-issue. Same thing for "making sure" that the user is who it says it is. What does that even mean? If you get a valid token, you proceed and authenticate the user the token represent. Either the user exists in your db or not. Care to elaborate?

Comment: To add to that, as the user dan.p correclty points out, all these tecniques are vulnerable to man in the middle and replay attacks. The commons strategy to avoid this is to fingerprint your requests so that two identical requests are rejected. HMAC (hashed message authentication code) is in this case the typical countermeasure, but clients and server must agree on an exchange format and the topic is so broad that spans over the question of the OP and would deserve a dedicated discussion.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would implement it is by introducing a proxy between the client (Backbone) and the RESTful webserver. The proxy manages authentication of users in conjunction with SSO. Therefore no need to change the api and/or client/webserver. Here a quick demo:

```
var http = require('http'),
    httpProxy = require('http-proxy'),
    express = require('express');

var proxy = new httpProxy.RoutingProxy();
var app = express();

function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (isLoggedIn) { return next(); }
  res.redirect('/');
}

// This should be your (RESTful) webserver
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
  res.write('request successfully proxied!' + '\n' + JSON.stringify(req.headers, true, 2));
  res.end();
}).listen(9000);

var isLoggedIn = false;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  console.log(isLoggedIn)
  res.send('Logged in? ' + isLoggedIn);
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res){
  isLoggedIn = true;
  res.redirect('/');
});

app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
  isLoggedIn = false;
  res.redirect('/');
});

app.all('/api/*', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
  return proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 9000
  });
});

app.listen(8000);
```

The first time you visit the page, you're logged out and any call to `/api/something` gets redirected to `/`. When you're logged (visit the `/login` page) all requests to `/api/*` are routed through the proxy to the webserver listening on port 9000.

In particular, when you set `app.all('/*', ...)` all the calls to your API server stay the same but are augmented with an authentication layer. The concept is trivial to extend with oauth (have a look at [passportjs](http://passportjs.org/) if you are using node).

Comment: Interesting possibility. Correct me if I am wrong, this means the server-side is still stateful, just that the RESTful API server part is stateless. If so, as a whole, the server is still stateful?

Comment: Correct, you RESTful API server is stateless but the proxy is stateful. From the perspective of the client, it may look like the server is stateful. However, the server is built from independent blocks that can be swapped and removed. So I won't necessarily call the whole architecture stateful because the API server is not. Indeed, this setup gives you the benefit of storing the sessions server side, without impacting on the statelessness of the API.

Comment: Hmm, I chanced upon storing sessions on redis. Does that make things any better? If the purpose of being stateless is scalability and storing state on 1 server doesnt scale, does storing state in redis help? Multiple server can access the same redis store? If multiple redis stores are required, we're back to square one again?

Comment: You can scale the proxy server horizontally by adding more proxy instances as long as those are connected to the same database. You can use redis to store sessions and you can scale redis using [replication](http://redis.io/topics/replication). But I believe 3rd party auth is not enough. Indeed, when you (successfully) log in through oauth you are given a token. Every subsequent call to the 3rd party service includes the token and the service authorises or denies the call. I don't see how you could store the 3rd party token and authorise a call to your API. how do you know if a token is valid?

Comment: I don't mean I check if the token is valid myself. I was thinking in a stateful app, tokens are stored in sessions on server (correct me if I am wrong) now if they are stored on a database is it any less stateful? Sorry I am kind of confused about  statelessness ...

Comment: If you are storing sessions, I believe you're stateful. Note that in this particular case just the proxy is stateful, but the api is still stateless. You can read more about statelessness and statefulness [here](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/stateless)

Answer (score 0):

You could adopt the approach used in Facebook's JavaScript SDK.

[This documentation page provides the quick-start to login vith Facebook for web.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/getting-started-web/) Not very deep, but explains the basic of how to use their approach. Does not mention the possibility of signature, however.

When registering Facebook logon for your app, you get an app secret from the application dashboard on Facebook.

When the user have logged on to your app via Facebook, your JavaScript gets an authentication object. This object contains a signature. (If you set it up correct in the dashboard.)

You can supply this authentication object with the client call to your RESTful server, and on the server check that the signature is correct. This way you know that the user was authenticated by facebook, is this user, and was authenticated for your application.

[This documentation page describes how to use the signed authentication.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/using-login-with-games/) Do not be intimidated by the "games" in the headline, it works perfectly fine for any web app.

Instead of allowing only Facebook for SSO, you can implement something in the same spirit as the FB login, using other OAUTH providers.

Use the solution suggested by danielepolencic, but modify it such that instead of a proxy in the same node.js instance you have another server for logins. This service does the OAUTH check with the provider, and maintains session with the client. It emits a signed token to the client, with a short time-to-live. The client must ask for a new token before the time-to-live ends.

You then implement a client-side JavaScript with functionality similar to Facebook JavaScript SDK for the login to be used by your application. This function can either poll for new tokens, or retrieve a new token on request, whatever is most efficient for the scenario.

The client supplies this token to the RESTful API on each request, and the server checks the signature. Just as for the Facebook SSO.

There still is a session, but it can be maintained visavis completely different machines. This service can be scaled independently of the servers with your RESTful api.

However, bear in mind that this approach can be susceptible to man-in-the-middle attacks and replay attacks. Probably unwise to use without https.